# How to set filter property through javascript or Jquery for a kendo dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a kendo dropdown list in cshtml. I wanted to set filter property in Jquery or javasctipt. Could you please tell me how to acheive this?
Appreciate your help on this.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("movies")
          .DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
          .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
          {
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "The Shawshank Redemption", Value ="1"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "The Godfather", Value ="2"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "The Godfather: Part II", Value ="3"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo.", Value ="4"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Pulp Fiction", Value ="5"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "12 Angry Men", Value ="6"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Schindler's List", Value ="7"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", Value ="8"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Inception", Value ="9"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "The Dark Knight", Value ="10"
              }
          })
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: if filter was not set upon creation, destroy and re-initialize with the filter

In JavaScript/jQuery get the dropdownlist and call destroy():

```
var dropdownlist = $("#movies").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.destroy();
```

Then recreate with filter:

```
$("#products").kendoDropDownList({
  dataTextField: "ProductName",
  dataValueField: "ProductID",
  dataSource: {
    transport: {
         read: {
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
         }
    }
  },
  filter: filt
});
```

**[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/aPuxi)**

Comment: Hi Ezanker,Thank you for the update  I tried with your approach but still it didnt work when i saw you demo you added filter property at the time of creation of kendo dropdown but in my case i didnt put filter property at the time of creation but i wanted to set this filter through jquery or javascript. Hope you understand my issue please help me on this Thanks

Comment: @SamanthKolisetty, In the demo. when you click the buttons after creation, the filer property is set to different values. See the button click event that is after creation.

Comment: i understand that but by default while foorming the dropdown you are setting the filter and on button click you are changing accordingly. In my case i didnt keep the filter property while creation but in jquery or javascript i wanted to set this filter property

Comment: @SamanthKolisetty, i updated answer and demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/aPuxi

Comment: Thank you ezanker. It worked after i destroy. The same i have tried i forgot to destroy. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Could you please help me with the below thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278726/pdf-embeded-in-html-page-scroll-bar-issue